# Open subscheme in special fiber

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $R$ a discrete valuation ring with generic fiber irreducible. Can an open subscheme of $X$ be contained in the special fiber of $X$ ? Or is it true that every open subscheme of $X$ dominates $Spec(R)$ ?

Comment: Well, the special fiber is a closed subscheme of $X$, and since opens are always dense, they cannot be contained in closed subschemes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed even when it is not irreducible, one can restrict to a irreducible component.